# Reverse a generic list?

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

```
public static <T> List<T> arrayListReverse(List<T> lst) {
  ArrayList reversed= new ArrayList();
  for (int i=lst.size()-1;i>=0;i--){
  <T> t= lst.get(i);
  reversed.add(t);
  }
 return reversed;
 }
```

I want to be be able to return a list that is a reversed version of the original list. It should be able to work for any type. I keep getting errors when it comes to the  t=input.get(i);
Edit: I would like to only use the List interface

Comment: Just write `T` and not `<T>` in `<T> t= lst.get(i);`. This is because the type of the variable is `T`.

Comment: Unless for an exercise, use `Collections.reverse`.

Comment: Thank you. However, I am getting this:2 warnings found: Warning: unchecked call to add(E) as a member of the raw type java.util.ArrayList Warning: unchecked conversion required: java.util.List<T> found: java.util.ArrayList –

Answer (score 5):

```
public static <T> List<T> arrayListReverse(List<T> lst) {
    Collections.reverse(lst);
    return lst;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`<T>` should be `T`:

```
public static <T> List<T> arrayListReverse(List<T> lst) {
    ArrayList reversed= new ArrayList();
    for (int i=lst.size()-1;i>=0;i--){
      T t = lst.get(i);
      reversed.add(t);
    }
   return reversed;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. However, I am getting this:2 warnings found:

Warning: unchecked call to add(E) as a member of the raw type java.util.ArrayList
Warning: unchecked conversion
  required: java.util.List<T>
  found:    java.util.ArrayList

Comment: You just need reverse of list Or reverse of string in the reversed list too?

Answer (score 1):

In your code `<T> t =` should just be `T t =`, but you could also use a [`for-each` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) and add to the front of your `reversed` as you iterate forward. And, you shouldn't use [raw types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) (you didn't specify a generic for `reversed`) and you could use the diamond operator `<>`. And you could initialize your output list with the same initial size as your input. Something like

```
public static <T> List<T> arrayListReverse(final List<T> lst) {
    List<T> reversed = new ArrayList<>(lst.size());
    for (T t : lst) {
        reversed.add(0, t);
    }
    return reversed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this:

```
ArrayList reversed = new ArrayList();
reversed=Collections.reverse(startArray);
```

[Documentation:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse%28java.util.List%29)

> public static void reverse(List list)
>
> Reverses the order of the elements in the specified list.
>
> This method runs in linear time.
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> list - the list whose elements are to be reversed.
>
> **Throws:**
>
> UnsupportedOperationException - if the specified list or its list-iterator does not support the set operation.

Comment: this does not preserve generic , response for  Collections.reverse(new ArrayList<Integer>()) will be just ArrayList(), generic type will be lost

Answer (score 0):

If you really want the method to return the same type of list, as is given as parameter, use the following:

```java
    public static <T,L extends List<T>> L reverse(L list){
        Collections.reverse(list);
        return list;
    }
```

This will return a `Vector<String>`, if you pass a Vector of Strings.
It will return an `ArrayList<Something>`, if you pass an ArrayList of Somethings.
It will return a `LinkedList<Doom>`, when you pass a LinkedList of Doom.

I think, you get the idea.

Btw., [Madushan Perera`s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33699982/1285585) answer will also return the same Type as passed, but in that case you would have to cast, if assigning to the original variable.